# CKEditor upgrade from 3.6 to 4, found Aspell plug in port to 4 doesn't work

Tags: java, javascript, ckeditor, aspell

I am upgrading CKEditor from 3.6 to 4, we use Aspell 3.x and we want to continue using the Aspell plug in, as all other spell checkers require adverts or payment, or are just not good enough.

I have found files online of what claims to be a port to use Aspell with 4: https://support.capana.com/otrs-web/js/thirdparty/ckeditor-4.0/plugins/aspell/

But whenever it is run it throws

```
     "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Config' of undefined"
```

on the lines:

```
    SessionName = opener.Core.Config.Get('SessionName'),
    SessionID = opener.Core.Config.Get('SessionID');
```

in the file spellchecker.html in spellerpages.

This is not a question exactly to fix it, just wondering if anyone can help with solving this problem/finding someone who has been in the same situation/just general help.

Thanks

UPDATE:

I have modified the Aspell 4 port I have found to become a generic 4 Aspell plugin, the problem before was that the one I found was catered for a specific system. If anyone wants my new copy, let me know!

Comment: Can you put your modified plugin on github?

Comment: I can't, after I emailed them, Tim that works at widgit upgraded the plugin and sent it to me, so they should have an updated version on there website by now? if not then email tim and ask him to send you a copy.

Comment: Do you have a link to where Tim that works at Widgit uploaded the plugin? I am also in need of the plugin. Thanks